# Ryzen 7 4800, Ubuntu 20.04.02: Display and/or USB problems

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04 on an ASUS PN50 mini-PC with Ryzen 7 4800. Upgraded to 20.04.2, kernel 5.8.0-44-lowlatency. Memory 32 GB 3200 MHz. Installation itself was smooth. The box only runs Radeon graphics. There is no NVIDIA. The desktop is Xfce 4.14.

I may be mixing apples and oranges, but since I can't tell (I'm not a hw freak) I'll report more than one issue. They may or may not be related, please bear with me.

**Prelude:** After installation the system didn't seem to boot. Stuck with Ubuntu splash screen.

On closer look lightdm wouldn't start. This fact kept the system waiting indefinitely.

I modified /etc/default/grub, deleted "quiet splash", added "nomodeset". The system now boots to text. After logging in I do a manual "startx" and the box generally seems to behave well. Graphics look good, snappy response.
Later I added "amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1" to grub, but I haven't noticed any difference. The gpumanager log ends with "Nothing to do".

I'm not sure what lightdm does, but it is the default display manager:
/etc/X11/default-display-manager: /usr/sbin/lightdm

Here is `systemctl status lightdm.service` output. I'm not sure what it's telling me.

```
lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-15 10:08:48 CET; 4h 12min ago
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
    Process: 1519 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1522 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1522 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mar 15 10:08:48 blizzard systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
mar 15 10:08:48 blizzard systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
mar 15 10:08:48 blizzard systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 15 10:08:48 blizzard systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 15 10:08:48 blizzard systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
```

I have disabled everything in the Xfce Power Manager so it should never interfere.

**Issue 1:** What about lightdm? Is it a problem?

**Issue 2:** If I leave the box for more than a couple of minutes there is no more keyboard response. The mouse pointer moves, but clicks have no effect. (All USB.) First I thought the screen had frozen, but it hasn't. I can ssh into the box and, for instance, kill a task and it disappears from the screen. Over a ssh connection the box appears completely alive, including "ssh -X". -- Same thing happens on waking up after suspend.

This keeps me hacking away. As long as I do the box stays responsive, alive and kicking.

**Issue 3:** I cannot set up more than one physical screen. Connecting a HDMI screen works well. So does a USB DisplayPort screen. If both are plugged in the USB DisplayPort gets priority. In either case only one screen is visible in the Display settings (or ARandR) and it has to be plugged in at boot time. If I unplug the USB DisplayPort screen it's lost and cannot be connected again.
(In contrast, this works well on a somewhat older Ubuntu box where DisplayLink is installed.)

[SIDE NOTE: Can't find a Stackoverflow tag for Ryzen.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of lightdm crash course, here is the answer, and it has nothing to do with Ryzen.

One file was missing from the lightdm configuration. This is an installation from scratch, so either it's missing from the Ubuntu Studio distribution, or maybe I unwittingly deleted it myself somehow.

The file is: `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

The omission made lightdm complain (in `lightdm.log`)

```
Seat seat0: Failed to find session configuration default
Seat seat0: Failed to create greeter session
```

Adding the file solved all 3 issues, confirming they were related. The unresponsiveness ("Issue 2") was the result of screenlock setting in without a proper screen configuration.

For those who, like me, dive into lightdm without previous experience, I recommend running `lightdm --show-config` to compare the output with that obtained from a working system. By all means, also install Xephyr (package name xserver-xephyr) to be able to run `lightdm --debug --test-mode`. Wonderful.